# WiFi bandwidth issues on single computer

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

On my workstation I have had a great deal of issues with the wifi speeds. When I plug into the router I get ~80Mbps. When I use WiFi I get an average of ~3Mbps (on both a 2.4 GHz network and a 5GHz network).

I have done a great deal of 'Google'ing to attempt to find a solution myself but haven't had any solid results.

I also want to point out that I have tested several other devices on the network and they are getting better speeds. Additionally, I have attempted to use three separate wifi adapters to troubleshoot. two internal and one USB. All to no avail. I did reset TCP/IP stack as well. Nothing.

What can I do?

Comment: What Wi-Fi standards do your devices support – are they capable of _at least_ 802.11n (aka "Wireless-N"), or are they limited to .11a/b/g?

Comment: Yeah they do. [Here is the spec sheet of the one I have in it now](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/PCEN10/specifications/)